# jqplot conversion to image doesn't show y-axis html

Tags: javascript, php, html, jqplot

I have added html in y-axis ticks and it is printing fine in browser window.

[image: Browser window show it like this]

However, when I convert the graph to image using $('#chart').jqplotToImageStr({}), it strips the html part of the tick.

[image: image using jqplotToImageStr({})]

**What I Tried?**

I tried escaping HTML through jqplot and also decoded ticks in PHP using html_entity_decode with no luck with either.

**Desired Result**

I want the converted image contain the HTML part (green,yellow, red boxes) of the tick printed in image as well.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is looking for an answer.

Add following lines to the core jqplot lib at line 9201.

```
if ($(el).css('background-color') && $(el).css('width') && $(el).css('height')){
   newContext.fillStyle = $(el).css('background-color');
   newContext.fillRect(left, top, $(el).css('width'), $(el).css('height'));
}
```